# Solution of $p(1+q)=qz$

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Solve the Partial differential equation

> $$p(1+q)=qz$$

Here $p=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $q=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$

I tried assuming $p=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=a$, where $a$ is some constant.
Then we get $q=\frac{a}{z-a}$

Then $$dz=adx+\frac{a}{z-a}dy$$

I am stuck here?

Comment: Where are the partial derivatives in that equation??

Comment: By standard notation $p=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $q=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ which is followed by indian authors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For equations of type $\boxed{\color{blue}{\phi(z,p,q) = 0}}$ (i.e., without $x, y$ explicitly),
assume $\boxed{\color{blue}{u=x+ky}} \text{ and }  z = f(u) = f(x+ky)$.

Now, $p = \dfrac{dz}{du}\cdot1, q = \dfrac{dz}{du}\cdot k$.

Here,

$\dfrac{dz}{du}\left(1+k\dfrac{dz}{du}\right) = kz\dfrac{dz}{du}$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{kdz}{kz-1} = du $

$\Rightarrow \ln(kz-1) = u +c $

$\Rightarrow \boxed{\ln(kz-1) = x+ky+c}$

Comment: You made my day thanku

Comment: You're welcome!